# Is there a better or more efficient way of displaying database entries to textboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Login"].Rows)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dr["Id"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dr["username"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dr["u_password"].ToString();
        textBox4.Text = dr["exp"].ToString();
        textBox5.Text = dr["salary"].ToString();
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adpt);
    }
```

This is what I've got at the moment.  Obviously, this is just a smaller scope workaround and is not efficient enough for a whole management system.

Comment: Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: Why not to use DataGrids?

Comment: @Greg Sorry I didn't mention it, it's a winform.

Comment: Use a binding source and bind each of the text boxes that way.  It would be a nearly codeless solution.

Comment: How many rows are there in `ds.Tables["Login"].Rows`, and why are you creating and discarding that `SqlCommandBuilder` on every iteration? And what makes you think you have a performance problem?

Comment: @EdPlunkett there are four rows in that table ,I've put the sqlcommandbuilder out of the loop now didn't notice that, and I'm not receiving performance issues, I want a faster way of adding entries into textboxes, so that if there are more rows in the future I can add them without using "textBox.Text = dr[""].ToString();"  for every row

Comment: So you're assigning four different values to `textBox1.Text`, `textBox2.Text`, etc. The first three will never be seen. Is there a reason for that approach? If you could answer my other questions too, that'd be great.

Comment: @EdPlunkett edited my comment answering the rest, sorry about that

Comment: OK, so by "efficiency" you don't mean that in the programming sense, you just want to save some typing. I still don't understand what your code is intended to do. By "more rows in the future", do you mean "more columns in the future"? I mean, in your database programming terminology, is a "row" a line of code rather than a row in a database?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Apologies, didn't mean to use "efficient" in that way. Also yes I do mean "more columns in the future".

Comment: @Repub619 I don't think you're going to do any better than what you've got. If you switch to Entity Framwork, you'd have intellisense for the database columns, FWIW. I think Greg's suggestion (see his answer below) would be some fun code to write, but in practice is suspect it would be a fair bit more work, net, than what you have now. It also scatters the details of the field-to-control mapping off out of sight.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ah well thanks for the help anyway, I have not got around to learning entity framework or how it's used yet but I'll try implementing it into this once I have done so.

Comment: No great need to rush into EF in my opinion.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I agree about Entity Framework, I often find Dapper the speed and efficiency without the extra agony of Entity Framework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could take the following approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControl<TControl>(this Control control) where TControl : Control
{
     if(control.Controls == null)
          Enumerable.Empty<TControl>();

     var children = control.Controls.OfType<TControl>();
     return children.SelectMany(ctrl => GetChildControl<TControl>(ctrl)).Concat(children);
}
```

So the above method would basically do recursion for a specific Control, for instance `Textbox`.  So you would use in the following manner:

```
var fields = this.GetChildControl<TControl>(Textbox);
foreach(var item in fields)
{
     // You would have some conditional, or map to an attribute or some property 
    //  identifier, to automatically map the value to an object directly.
}
```

So once you compare the property name or attribute to the actual Control name, or something you could automatically map.  But, keep this in mind.  Depending on the Control's you wish access to.  You could end up with an abundant amount of loops.  Through all the Controls and through the Properties.  This could impede your performance quite a bit.  So be wary, in Web Forms I used a similar mapping technique and the recursion found so many Controls that it became a large loop to iterate, which made the page slow.

Additional warning, this is a lot of Reflection.  Which some developers dislike, due to the extra complexity.

Some really good questions exist with different approaches, or similar that accomplish this.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction.  Obviously once you have an object you can use an ORM or Micro ORM to quickly hit the database.

---

Dapper Example:

```
dbConnection.ExecuteQuery<Sample>(getSampleQuery);
```

I believe that is your grand intent.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll try your method and let you know if it worked.